# Can the Japanese version be played in English?

Tags: version-differences, pokemon-conquest

Can the Japanese version of *Pokémon Conquest* be played in English (via a setting menu or something)? Or can that version of Pokémon Conquest only be played in the Japanese language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used to own Japanese version (it's called ポケモン+ノブナガの野望 if you care), and as far as I recall, that version only includes Japanese. Start menu doesn't comes with settings, just New game or Continue. Also, in-game settings doesn't comes with language settings. If you want to play in English, just buy English version.

I think I still have them as ROM in somewhere in my HDDs, so if you want to be sure about it, let me know; I'll take a time to take screen shots.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A picture would be nice but, not necessary. I’ll be just as happy to take your word for it. 

I was originally going to buy the game in English, but the Japanese version sells for a lot cheaper. (Which is why I asked the question). But, it sounds like I’ll need to buy an English copy.